# VBA: Runtime Error '70' when accessing a database

Tags: vba, database-connection

I have an .xlsm-file. It contains a list of movies, and is supposed to search the online database omdbapi.com for information on each movie, and insert this information, starting in column `F`.

A MWE looks as follows.

In the first sheet, it says just `Lawless (2012)` in cell A1, the name of the first movie. Columns 4 and 5 contain the name with spaces turned to `+` and the year extracted from the first cell, respectively, but I skip that code here. In the example, it looks like this:

[image]

The VBA macro is as follows:

```
Sub test()

mystr = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=" & Cells(1, 4).Value & "&y=" & Cells(1, 5).Value & "&r=xml"
        ActiveWorkbook.XmlImport URL:=mystr, ImportMap:=Nothing, Overwrite:=True, Destination:=Cells(1, 6)
            ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Item(1).Delete

End Sub
```

This has code has worked for the longest time. Now, I encounter the error:

> Run-time error '70':
>
> Permission denied.

I searched what that means, but did not find anything that seemed applicable.
Furthermore, the internet connection is working and not clogged up by other connections, and excel has all rights to access the web.

Comment: The site says "05/10/17 - New API Keys! Due to some security concerns on how the keys were being distributed I updated the form to email them and also changed the algorithm used, which means your older keys not obtained through email will eventually stop working." Are you aware of this?

Comment: As @Tehscript points out, you probably need a newer API key.  And your code doesn't even seem to pass the (older?) key because it says the usage should include a `apikey` parameter (`http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=[yourkey]&`)

Comment: I was not aware of this. It didn't cross my mind that the site might have changed.

Comment: "This has code has worked for the longest time. Now, I encounter the error Run-time error '70': Permission denied." - that should really have been a huge tip-off that the site had changed.  (You didn't change your code, so the next most likely explanation is that someone changed the site.)

Comment: well, this was indeed trivial. If you want to make that an answer, I can award that bounty.

Answer (score -4):

please try this ... the result may answer your question about the code 70

```
Sub test()

    mystr = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=" & Cells(1, 4).Value & "&y=" & Cells(1, 5).Value & "&r=xml"

    Debug.Print mystr       ' copy the url from the "Immediate window"
                            ' and paste into a web browser address bar,
                            ' then navigate to that webpage
                            ' (view immediate window by pressing ctrl-G)

End Sub
```